# Как редактировать html через wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, админка

Как редактировать html/css через админку wordpress и возможно ли это вообще?

Comment: html - никак. Невозможно. А style.css - пожалуйста. Внешний вид->Редактор

Comment: И, кстати, какой html вы собрались редактировать в WordPress?

Comment: А лучше всего забыть о том, что этот редактор в админке существует. Сайт завалить легко, а исправить без ftp невозможно. Редактировать файлы стоит с помощью ftp или современной IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В админ панели Внешний вид -> Редактор, выбираете нужный файл css или файлы шаблона с расширением php.

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос очень расплывчатый. Все зависит от того какая тема на сайте, как создана тема и др. В зависимости от темы, в нем могут быть разные редакторы страниц( [VisualComposer](https://visualcomposer.io/), [BeaverBuilder](https://www.wpbeaverbuilder.com/), [DiviBuilder](https://www.elegantthemes.com/plugins/divi-builder/)) с помощью которых вы можете изменить структуру страницы( добавить или удалить текст, картинки и др. ). Или же страница может быть создана с помощью текстового и `html` редактора WordPress( по умолчанию она есть ).

Конкретно в WordPress нету `.html` файлов. Она создана с помощью языка программирования `.php`. Все темы имеют общие для WordPress файлы: `templates`. Есть template частичные(`header.php`, `footer.php`) и есть целые страницы. Вы можете посмотреть в офф. документации список всех файлов [`templates`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-files/), также их [`архитектуру`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

Также в темах есть `.css` файлы( `style.css` обьязательный ). Но если хотите добавить `css` стили без их потери в будущем( обновление темы ),  тогда лучше добавить их в дочернюю тему или в настройке WordPress( будет сохранена в базе данных ):

```
Dashboard -> Appearance -> Customize -> Additional CSS
```

Answer (score 0):

Есть такой плагин [Custom css](https://www.silkypress.com/simple-custom-css-js-pro/) там можно добавлять код и css html и js, а если вы хотите изменить именно html темы, то нужно зайти wp-content\themes<название темы>\искомые файлы ну они все будут генерироваться динамический так что придется искать очень долго ну для этого есть notepad++ ,с начало скачайте саму тему на свой компьютер и например вы хотите найти название класса и по инструкции  откройте [Notepad++.](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

Нажмите на клавиши Ctrl+F для того, чтобы открыть инструмент Найти и заменить (Find and replace).

Откройте вкладку Найти в файлах (Find in files). Заполните поле Что искать: (Find what:) и выберите папку для поиска (папка с файлами вашего сайта, папка с файлами шаблона, папка темы, и т. д.)

и так можете изменять